# asp.net mvc 4 end request in AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

In our asp.net mvc 4 project, we use `AuthorizeAttribute` to implement access control,our code like this

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (IsValid())
        {
            //do something
        }
        else
        {
            httpContext.Response.Redirect("~/Common/NoAuthorize", true);
        }
    }
    protected bool IsValid()
    {
        //custom authentication logic
        return true;
    }
}
```

The MVC `Controller` tagged with `MyAuthorizeAttribute`.The problem is when user is invalid,it should redirect to a NoAuthorize page immediately.But I found out that it will still run the code in MVC `Controller`.The `Redirect` works after that.

I try to add `httpContext.Response.End()` and `HttpContext.Current.Response.End()`.Neither of them work.So how can I do the redirect immediately without running the code in `Controller`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AuthorizeCore should be returning a bool value. You do not do the redirect from that method. You should alter the route from the HandleUnauthorizedRequest method

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    if (IsValid())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

protected bool IsValid()
{
    //custom authentication logic
    return true;
}

protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext) {

    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                               new RouteValueDictionary 
                               {
                                   { "action", "ActionName" },
                                   { "controller", "ControllerName" }
                               });
}
```

Comment: Thanks!Your answer is a easy way.I find something easier just now.If  `AuthorizeCore` return `false`,the code in certain action of `Controller` will not be run too.

Answer (score 0):

You could throw an exception.

```
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (IsValid())
        {
            //do something
        }
        else
        {
            // You can throw any exception even custom.
            throw new AuthenticationException("User must be logged in to access this page.");
        }
    }
```

It depends on how you handle exception in your application. I have implemented below method in `Global.asax.cs`. Inside this method, I check if it is not a `HttpException` and if it is `AuthenticationException` then redirect it to ErrorController's appropriate action, in this case Forbidden method.

```
    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ex = Server.GetLastError();

        if (ex is HttpException)
        {
            var httpEx = ex as HttpException;
            statusCode = httpEx.GetHttpCode();

            switch (httpEx.GetHttpCode())
            {
                case 400:
                    action = "BadRequest";
                    break;

                case 401:
                    action = "Unauthorized";
                    break;

                case 403:
                    action = "Forbidden";
                    break;

                case 404:
                    action = "PageNotFound";
                    break;

                case 500:
                    action = "CustomError";
                    break;

                default:
                    action = "CustomError";
                    break;
            }
        }
        else if (ex is AuthenticationException)
        {
            action = "Forbidden";
            statusCode = 403;
        }

        httpContext.ClearError();
        httpContext.Response.Clear();
        httpContext.Response.StatusCode = statusCode;
        httpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
        routeData.Values["controller"] = "Error";
        routeData.Values["action"] = action;

        controller.ViewData.Model = new HandleErrorInfo(ex, currentController, currentAction);
        ((IController) controller).Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext), routeData));
    }
```

`ErrorController` `Forbidden()` action will redirect to appropriate page as shown below:

```
    [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Forbidden()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;

        var model = (ViewData.Model as HandleErrorInfo);
        string returnUrl = string.Empty;

        if (model != null)
        {
            returnUrl = Url.Action(model.ActionName, model.ControllerName);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account", new { returnUrl = returnUrl, name = "" });
    }
```